# How to remove [0/0] from upper right when pane clicked in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In my .tmux.conf I have:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
```

This works good, except whenever I click on a pane in the upper right corner I get a flashing "[0/0]". Which appears on left mouse down, and disappears on left mouse up. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by just having

```
set -g mouse-select-pane on
```

in the .tmux.conf file. I had to remove the mode-mouse line.